# How to load more pages from the Reddit API?

Tags: jquery, json, api, reddit

I have a simple question. I am fairly new to the entire API area and I am working with the Reddit API at the moment. What I want to do is basically load more than just one page of the subreddit I am pulling JSON from. I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.

This is what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) {
    $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
    });
});
```

You can see a live JsFiddle here: [Reddit JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/thedarklord1939/V6eT2/2/)

My question is:

**How can I load more content from other pages? [I believe it is only showing page #1]** Can anyone here give me a link or a JsFiddle that shows how to do it?

Also, if anyone here is feeling generous, my aspiration is to fetch more information as the person keeps scrolling down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the after parameter like

```
var lastId;

function load(params) {
    params = params || {};
    $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", params, function (data) {
        var children = data.data.children;
        $.each(children, function (i, item) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
        });
        if (children && children.length > 0) {
            lastId = children[children.length - 1].data.id;
        } else {
            lastId = undefined;
        }
    });
}

load();

$('.after').click(function () {
    if (lastId) {
        load({
            after: 't3_' + lastId
        });
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KVLAH/)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796468/how-does-pagination-on-reddits-home-page-work)

Comment: That does something. When I click "Load" I get the same page. Is it possible to load the second page, then the third page consecutively? What is the part in the URL that basically tells it to load a page?